# Gyroscope: Rotational difference Android

Tags: java, android, gyroscope

How can I get by how much a device has been rotated?
What I mean is if I start off with an initial position, and turned 90 degrees, how can I make this code tell me that I have turned 90 degrees? So sorry for the sloppiness of the question. Here's my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AccessGyroscope extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
//a TextView
private TextView tv;
//the Sensor Manager
private SensorManager sManager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //get the TextView from the layout file
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    //get a hook to the sensor service
    sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
}

//when this Activity starts
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    /*register the sensor listener to listen to the gyroscope sensor, use the 
     * callbacks defined in this class, and gather the sensor information as  
     * quick as possible*/
    sManager.registerListener(this, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}

//When this Activity isn't visible anymore
@Override
protected void onStop() 
{
    //unregister the sensor listener
    sManager.unregisterListener(this);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) 
{
    //Do nothing
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{
    //if sensor is unreliable, return void
    if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
    {
        return;
    }

    //else it will output the Roll, Pitch and Yawn values
    tv.setText("Orientation Z (Yaw) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[0]));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The TYPE_ORIENTATION sensor is deprecated, do not use it because it doesnt work well and is computationally intensive.

Use [getRotationMatrix][1] passing in accellerometer and magnetic field readings, and then use getRotation () on the matrix. 
This is almost verbatim from the developer reference:

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix(float[], float[], float[], float[]) "getRotationMatrix ()"

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. I'm fairly new to using sensors in android, so if you would give me a sample code to guide me in the right direction, that would sort me right out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest of solutions can sometimes be difficult to find.

I added 3 buttons: 1 to catch the initial position, 1 to catch the final position, and one to subtract the both.